# Add parameter to dygraph

Tags: r, dygraphs

I am trying to change the digits after the decimal in the dygraph being displayed but I get this error:

```
Error in dygraph(indoConc, { : object 'digitsAfterDecimal' not found
```

Code

```
library(dygraphs)
lungDeaths <- cbind(mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths)

indoConc <- Indometh[Indometh$Subject == 1, c("time", "conc")]
dygraph(indoConc,{digitsAfterDecimal:1})
```

Dygraph link to section: [here](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#digitsAfterDecimal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dygraph(indoConc) %>% dyOptions(digitsAfterDecimal=1)
```

for more options, see http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/dygraphs/html/dyOptions.html

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to set the sigFigs option since trailing zeros won't be displayed with digitsAfterDecimal, it depends on your data.

```
dygraph(indoConc) %>%
dyOptions(sigFigs=1)
```

Also, it seems like you are confusing Java scripting with the R code used for dygraphs in R. Here is the link to the dygraphs for R package documentation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dygraphs/dygraphs.pdf